# IF formula returning the wrong value in only the first cell. Nested in Array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I believe the third If the statement and if statements after are returning true when it should return False for only the first cell (k2).
IF($E$2:$E >= 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2)

Full Statement

- IF($E$2:$E >= 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2, IF((('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$5 ) <= ($E$2:$E * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4)), ('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$5), $E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4 ) , IF((0 >=($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2) * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4),0,(($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2)*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4)))

K2 and k3 should both return ; 0
K3; K is correct

**Formula**
=ArrayFormula(IF(($E$2:$E = ""),"",(IF(('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$H$5) <= ($E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$H$4),('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$H$5),($E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$H$4))) + (IF(($E$2:$E >='Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2),IF( (('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$3 * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$4) <= ($E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$4)),('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$5),($E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$4)),($E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$4) )) + IF($E$2:$E >= 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2, IF((('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$5 ) <= ($E$2:$E * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4)), ('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$5), $E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4 ) , IF((0 >=($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2) * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4),0,(($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2)*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4))) + IF($E$2:$E >= 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$2, IF((('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$5 ) <= ($E$2:$E * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$4)), ('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$5), $E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$4 ) , IF((0 >=($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2) * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4),0,(($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2)*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$4))) + IF($E$2:$E >= 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$2, IF((('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$5 ) <= ($E$2:$E * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$4)), ('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$5), $E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$4 ) , IF((0 >=($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$2) * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$4),0,(($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$K$2)*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$L$4)))))

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa9qb.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w42i.png

Comment: Share a sample workbook then show your input and expected output. Explain logic to gain that output in brief. I believe there may some other formula to achieve desired output.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. As you see, your formula is very complex and it's hard to squeeze it in one's head without a working spreadsheet. Please cut all the sensitive data and share a working example. If you can't get your results, please share input and desired output.